# how to insert elements in the middle of LinkedList using a ListIterator

Tags: java, iterator, linked-list

I want to create an empty LinkedList and using a ListIterator, add Integers to the List by always inserting them in the middle of the List.  How to do that most efficiently.

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inserting elements into a LinkedList at an index is inherently inefficient. Use an ArrayList or something else instead of LinkedList if you must insert at an index.

But if you need info on using ListIterators, look here:

http://www.java-examples.com/iterate-through-elements-java-linkedlist-using-listiterator-example

Or else you might just consider doing

```
myLL.add(i,val)
```

For more info see the Java API.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html

Comment: actually, both ArrayList and LinkedList have their inefficiencies in regards to this operation.  the traversal is O(n) for the LinkedList, but the insertion is O(n) for the ArrayList.

Comment: Good to note. I was just answering about insertion though since that's what OP asked about.

Comment: Inserting elements into a LinkedList is not inefficient when you use a ListIterator. It should be O(1) actually.

Comment: @PhilippWendler - as i said, for LinkedList it's the _traversal_ that is inefficient, not the insertion.

Comment: @jtahlborn Well said about either option having an O(n) step somewhere in there.  What about using a `LinkedHashSet`?  This way, the traversal and insertion would both be O(1).

Comment: @The111 - a LinkedHashSet doesn't let you insert items in the "middle" of the iteration, so it wouldn't work for the OP's scenario.  and if you are always adding to the end, then LinkedList/ArrayList are roughly equivalent in efficiency (ignoring the occassional resize of an ArrayList).

Comment: Yeah, I realized later that it uses Iterator and not ListIterator. :-(

Answer (score 2):

Something like this? (is it an excersize from Bruce Eckel's Thinking in Java? ;))
The question about effeciency anyway remains open...

```
public class Excersize14 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedList< Integer > list = new LinkedList<Integer>() ;

            getIterator( list ).add( 10 );
            getIterator( list ).add( 20 );
            getIterator( list ).add( 30 );
            getIterator( list ).add( 40 );
            getIterator( list ).add( 50 );
            getIterator( list ).add( 60 );

            System.out.println( list );
    }

    private static ListIterator<Integer> getIterator(LinkedList<Integer> list) {
            return list.listIterator( list.size() / 2 );
    }
}
```